# Correct use of “où” when linking two independent clauses

Tags: conjonctions, indications-de-lieu, subordonnées

I want to link the two following independent propositions into one sentence using a single pronoun so that I have a subordinate clause.

> Je vais te montrer l'université ;  je vais à cette université

I think it might be 'où'

> Je vais te montrer l'université où je vais

Is that grammatically correct?

Comment: Je pense qu'on dirait « je vais te montrer l'université à laquelle j'assiste » plutôt qu'avec aller.

Comment: @ncm: on « assiste » à un cours, mais on « va » à l'université (ou on « suit des cours » à l'université).

Comment: « Je vais te montrer l’université où j’étudie » me semble tout de même plus judicieux.

Comment: @Édouard: qui donc « étudie » à l'université de nos jours ? Sérieusement personne ne dit ça.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Peut-être est-ce dû à des spécificités locales, mais pour moi, « aller à Pétaouchnok 12 » veut dire « se diriger vers le campus de Pétaouchnok 12 ».

Comment: @Édouard: je suis tout à fait d'accord que la version « bon français » c'est « l'université où j'étudie ». En pratique comme le verbe n'importe que très peu dans cette subordonnée ma constatation c'est que *aller* est beaucoup plus courant. Euh, sinon Pétaouchnok 12, c'est une tentative de généralisation ratée :-)

Answer (score 5):

C'est parfaitement correct. *Où* est la conjonction de subordination qui reprend son antécédent (dans le cas présent, « l'université ») pour indiquer le lieu de l'action (« aller ») de la subordonnée.